# Is shared virtual memory used when multiple processes read a file using file pointer in Linux?

Tags: c++, linux, memory

I wrote a C++ program which read a file using file pointer. And I need to run multiple process at the same time. Since the size of file can be huge (100MB~), to reduce memory usage in multiple processes, I think I need use shared memory. (For example IPC library like `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object`)

But does it really need? Because I think if multiple processes read same file, then virtual memory of each processes mapped to same physical memory of file thru page table.

I read a Linux doc and they said,

> Shared Virtual Memory
>
> Although virtual memory allows processes to have separate (virtual)
>   address spaces, there are times when you need processes to share
>   memory. For example there could be several processes in the system
>   running the bash command shell. Rather than have several copies of
>   bash, one in each processes virtual address space, it is better to
>   have only one copy in physical memory and all of the processes running
>   bash share it. Dynamic libraries are another common example of
>   executing code shared between several processes. Shared memory can
>   also be used as an Inter Process Communication (IPC) mechanism, with
>   two or more processes exchanging information via memory common to all
>   of them. Linux supports the Unix TM System V shared memory IPC.

Also, wiki said,

> In computer software, shared memory is either
>
> - a method of inter-process communication (IPC), i.e. a way of exchanging data between programs running at the same time. One process
>     will create an area in RAM which other processes can access, or
> - a method of conserving memory space by directing accesses to what would ordinarily be copies of a piece of data to a single instance
>     instead, by using virtual memory mappings or with explicit support of
>     the program in question. This is most often used for shared libraries
>     and for XIP.

Therefore, what I really curious is that does shared virtual memory supported by OS level or not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is off-topic here, perhaps, but the answer is yes, it is.  "One process will create an area in RAM which other processes can access" - it is the OS and the various low-level mechanisms it provides "System V shared memory", for example, that facilitate that.  "virtual memory mappings" likewise.  The loading and linking and paging of "shared libraries" likewise (tho some of the latter happens in userspace)

Comment: I'm not sure precisely what you're asking, but it seems like mmap (http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap) is what you're looking for. 100MB isn't that large nowadays, at least compared to modern RAM sizes; if you have the RAM to spare and need the performance improvement, I'd say go for memory mapping.

Comment: @sabreitweiser   100MB is not a large memory usage, but if many multiple process runs and all of them load file on memory then it can be very huge memory usage. I already consider mmap and boost memory mapping library, but want to know this work is needed or not.

Comment: @SeongeunSo If my understanding is correct, mmap creates a single copy and then that copy is shared between the various processes. Whether that's better or worse than many processes accessing the same file is something you'll probably need to find through profiling, or at least telling us more about the use case. I'm not sure how much overhead is associated with a plain File object, besides the transparent caching at various levels, but I think you would need a significant number of processes to overcome the memory required to mmap the whole file.

Comment: I am not sure, if I understand correctly. Do you man that this happen automatically? One process opens a file, which is mapped into memory, and when another process opens the same file, the same memory mapping is used?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your first question - if you want your data to be accessible by multiple processes without duplication you'll definitely need some kind of a shared storage.

In C++ I'd surely use boost's `shared_memory_object`. That's a valid option to share (large) data among processes and it has good documentation with examples (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/interprocess/sharedmemorybetweenprocesses.html).

Using `mmap()` is a more low-level approach usually used in C. To use it as an IPC you'll have to make the mapped region *shared*. From http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html:

> MAP_SHARED
>
> Share this mapping.  Updates to the mapping are visible to
>                     other processes that map this file, and are carried
>                     through to the underlying file.  The file may not actually
>                     be updated until msync(2) or munmap() is called.

Also on that page there's an example of mapping a file to shared memory.

In either case there are at least two things to remember:

- You need synchronization if there are multiple processes that modify the shared data.
- You can't use pointers, only offsets from the beginning of the mapped region.
  Here's an explanation from the boost docs:

> If several processes map the same file/shared memory, the mapping address will be surely different in each process. Since each process might have used its address space in a different way (allocation of more or less dynamic memory, for example), there is no guarantee that the file/shared memory is going to be mapped in the same address.
>
> If two processes map the same object in different addresses, this invalidates the use of pointers in that memory, since the pointer (which is an absolute address) would only make sense for the process that wrote it. The solution for this is to use offsets (distance) between objects instead of pointers: If two objects are placed in the same shared memory segment by one process, **the address of each object will be different in another process but the distance between them (in bytes) will be the same.**

Regarding the OS support - yes, shred memory is an OS specific feature.
In Linux `mmap()` is actually implemented in kernel and modules and can be used to transfer data between user and kernel-space.

Windows also has it's specifics:

> Windows shared memory creation is a bit different from portable shared memory creation: the size of the segment must be specified when creating the object and can't be specified through truncate like with the shared memory object. Take in care that when the last process attached to a shared memory is destroyed the shared memory is destroyed so there is no persistency with native windows shared memory.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't make sense.

> I think I need use shared memory. (For example IPC library like `boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object).`

If you use shared memroy, the memory is shared.

> I think if multiple processes read same file, then virtual memory of each processes mapped to same physical memory of file thru page table.

Now you're talking about memory-mapped I/O. It isn't the same thing. However more probably it *is* what you need in this situation.